# Database Design Choices

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I'm trying to create a work schedule creator with multiple stores and each store with multiple employees. Each store can also access past schedule created, but only the current schedule is modifiable. The way I have my SQL database setup is that I have two tables, stores and employees. Each employee has a store they work for, and time for all the days of the week, so I saved employees from all the stores in one table and get them as necessary with queries.

My question is, should I add another column (week) to the employee table to designate which week that schedule is for, or create a new html file for each schedule for that store's past schedules? I like the second choice because it decreases the chances of my SQL database being corrupted. As past schedules are unmodifiable, I have no issues with it.

P.S. just to make sure: if i write to a file using php, say `$name = "monir"; write("My name is $name")`. Will the file say `"My name is $name"` or `"My name is monir"`?

Comment: I'm not a DBA, but I think you need a few more tables. You have USERS and STORES and need one for SCHEDULES. For schedules, I'd have USERID, STOREID, WEEKID, YEAR, DAY (of week), START, END. That would allow you to create split shifts as you could have multiple entries for that one day.

Comment: Oh, and you'd want an ARCHIVE field to flag old/non-editable schedules (or, alternatively, migrate those to an ARCHIVEDSCHEDULES table)

Comment: Thank you all for your advice. I will be posting the source code at my website (sitebloviate.com) once I'm done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the comments made by DA and the other solutions indicate, having a third table is the way to go. At a minimum, try having the following:

store:
 id | name | address | etc.

employee:
 id | first_name | last_name | etc.

schedule:
 id | store_id | employee_id | week | date | start_time | end_time

While week is redundant since date is stored, it allows you to query much faster. You don't need the archive/past bit because you can just query whether schedule.week is the current week or not.

Answer (score 4):

Following the concept of [Database normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) you should add another table called e.g. schedule which contains a reference to an employee and a store. In addition to that you should put your week number in this schedule table to uniquely identity your table row.

Comment: One reason for this is that you might have employees (even if not now, maybe in the future) who might work at more than one store.

Answer (score 1):

> My questions is should I add another
>   column (week) to the employee table

I would suggest creating a `schedules` table. Employees would then belong to the schedule and the schedule would belong to a store. This provides more flexibility and allows you to better store past schedules.

> I like the second choice because it
>   decreases the chances of my SQL
>   database being corrupted.

You don't want to avoid a dynamic solution (table) in favor of a static one (html page) simply to prevent users from updating information. You simply need to create access rules in your application.

Answer (score 1):

You should have store, employee and a table that joins the stores and employees as stores and employees do NOT have a one-to_one relationship. Everyone I have ever known who worked in retail has had times when they were asked to work at other stores.

Schedule should be in a separate table with the employee id, the week and the scheduled hours. A trigger should be put on this table to prevent schedules from past dates from being updated. Alternatively you could have a view that exposes only the current schedule and future schedules and make all updates use the view  but selects can use the whole table. This would allow a database admin to change the past schedules if need be but not the application since it only uses the view.

Answer (score 0):

I've actually just done something quite similar, but our system is a whole hell of a lot more complicated than this.

Personally, given your present structure, I'd choose to add the extra column. It's not too much more work, and will give you the ability to reproduce the HTML files after the fact. I know you don't want to be able to modify past schedules, but that's more what I'd call business logic - so just prevent it from being possible somewhere in your code.

I'd have otherwise suggested you add another extra table for "weeks". Give it an ID, the start date and the end date, then use that "week_id" elsewhere to save duplication. You could also separate out schedule entries from employee records, so each employee would have a unique ID and your "schedule" table would be: ID, employee_id, week_id, date, start_time, end_time.

It'd give you a lot more control over your queries and reduce the duplication in the database quite considerably for later on. Also, unless your database is really *really* unstable, corruption shouldn't be a problem.

For your P.S. - as long as you surround your output in double-quotes, PHP will interpolate your values. So you'll get "My name is monir", rather than "My name is $name".